# Unable to register schema using register() in python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, kafka-python

I am trying to register schema to confluent schema registry using python.

```
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient

subject_name = "new-schema"
schema_url = "https://{{ schemaRegistry }}:8081" 
sr = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_url)

schema = {"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "user",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "fname", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": "int"}
 ]
}

my_schema = sr.register(subject_name, schema)
```

I am getting error as

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'
```

This is a valid avro schema. Still getting this error. What is that I am missing in here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `dict`, try to pass [`schema_registry.client.schema.AvroSchema`](https://github.com/marcosschroh/python-schema-registry-client/blob/master/schema_registry/client/schema.py#L7):

```
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient, schema


schema_ = schema.AvroSchema({
    "namespace": "example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "user",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "fname", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": "int"}
    ]
})


my_schema = sr.register(subject_name, schema_)
```